# How to show Y-axis lable while using x-unified hovermode in plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, axes

I am using `x-unified` hovermode in plotly with subplots. Whenever I move cursor on the plot I want to basically show x-hover info plus corresponding Y value on Y-axis at the X hover location. How can I do that? Currently Y-axis info comes

[image]

In above image, along with x-hover I want to see Y values highlighted on Y-axis as well. Let me know how I can achieve that!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding `showspikes` to both axes:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.update_xaxes(showspikes=True)  # <-- add this line
fig.update_yaxes(showspikes=True)  # <-- add this line

fig.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I show corresponding X and Y values on the axes along with these `showspikes`?

Comment: @PratikGhodke Yes, you will find them in the hovertemplate. I updated the answer.

Comment: That's great but I want those values on X and Y-axis. Great example would be this tradingview chart - https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ%3AAAPL. Have a look!

Comment: @PratikGhodke Unfortunately, there is no such option. Because `hovermode` options do not involve hovermode for both axes at the same time. Try add this line `fig.update_layout(hovermode="x")` , you will find it only for x-axis. Please look at https://community.plotly.com/t/hover-label-position-on-y-axis/16806/4

Comment: Ahh, figured that much out. Thanks for the help. This is good as well.